# .map removes values in my column that are not specified in the mapping

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a variety of values in one of my columns in my pandas dataframe. Those include LIMITED LIABILITY CORP, CORPORATION, LIMITED LIABILITY PARTNER, Limited Liability Corporation

All I am trying to do is rename some of the values that are equivalent but are called differently. So here I want to rename Limited Liability Corporation as LIMITED LIABILITY CORP and same thing with the Partnership.

This is the code I have written using map:

```
Leads_updated['Business_Type'] = 
Leads_updated['Business_Type'].map({'Limited Liability Corporation': 
'LIMITED LIABILITY CORP', 'Limited Liability Partnership':'LIMITED LIABILITY 
 PARTNER'})
```

Now, it does properly change the values that I wanted to change, however, there are other values that I did not change in my code such as "Corporation" that are now gone from my pandas dataframe column.

Why is that and how can I fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected behavior for `map`. It sounds like you're looking for [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) instead, which will leave values unchanged if it is not in your dictionary keys:

```
Leads_updated['Business_Type'].replace({'Limited Liability Corporation': 'LIMITED LIABILITY CORP', 'Limited Liability Partnership':'LIMITED LIABILITY PARTNER'})
```

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea why I didn't use this, mind went completely blank I guess. Do you know, can you use .replace on an entire dataframe or only 1 column?

Comment: Either one. If you look at the docs, the example of how to use a dict as your replacement values shows some fancier examples, you can even pass it a nested dict and it will perform different replacements in different columns